# Setting up Background image for a canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to set up a image to a canvas but I am not able to do it. I am not able to find any mistake. The canvas comes up on the `inspect element` but the image is not setting up.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
       <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/styling.css">
        <script src="JavaScript/setImage.js"></script>-->
    </head>
    <body>

    <canvas id="canvas" style="color: #0cff15; -webkit-background-image: url(/cheque.jpg)" ></canvas>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set background image using css and you should give width and height property as well. Please see my demo below.

```css
#canvas{
  color: #0cff15; 
  background-image: url("http://www.backgroundsy.com/file/dust-background.jpg");
  -webkit-background-image: url("http://www.backgroundsy.com/file/dust-background.jpg");
  border:1px solid black;
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
}
```

```html
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Where is the link/

Answer (score 1):

You don't style a canvas element like a div. You have to get its context via javascript and draw into it. Search for "mdn canvas" for documentation and read a bit.